# Java regex replace ignoring the first match

Tags: java, regex

```
mediaSourceSpecificJunkCharacters=mediaSourceSpecificJunkCharacters+",";   
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\],",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(mediaSourceSpecificJunkCharacters);
while(matcher.find()) {
    String stringToMatch=matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println("string to match "+stringToMatch);
    originalText=originalText.replaceAll(stringToMatch.trim(),"");
}
```

here `originalText="this is data from youtube youtube1 youtube2 youtube3 youtube4";`
and `mediaSourceSpecificJunkCharacters=[youtube2],[youtube3],[youtube4]`

the first match is youtube3 and not youtube2....so youtube2 never gets replaced...why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have `youtube1` in your `mediaSourceSpecificJunkCharacters`. Change that to

```
    String mediaSourceSpecificJunkCharacters = "[youtube1],[youtube2],[youtube3],[youtube4]";
```

and also change your pattern to

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

if you want to replace `youtube4` too, the `,` at the end prevents this in your code.

Comment: sorry..i have changed it..still d same

Comment: hi..thanks..it works..only that the case sensitivity part does not.If you provide YOUTUBE..as the input.. youtube does not get replaced..??

Comment: That's true. The case sensitivity part only applies to the matcher part, not to the replaceAll() call. You can fix this by adding `"(?i)"` to the replace expression. See this updated code: http://ideone.com/7d7TG

Comment: okay..got it..thanx..can u please also help with replacement of characters like *.?> etc in mediaSourceSpecificJunkCharacters which are regex metacharacters.Do all of them need to be handled separately or is there any easier way...?

Comment: They will need to be prefixed with a backslash. Since Strings themselves have a special meaning for `\ ` you must write `\\ `. So if you for example want to match the exact string `youtube.` you will have to write `youtube\\.`.